# Paypal disputes sandbox testing, trigger CUSTOMER.DISPUTE.RESOLVED event

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am trying to trigger **CUSTOMER.DISPUTE.RESOLVED** event for disputes testing in sandbox, for that i made a test payment and opened a dispute in the resolution center. To trigger dispute resolved event i wanna call settle dispute method https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/v1#disputes-actions_adjudicate.
However i am not able to do that, cuz after create dispute is in **WAITING_FOR_SELLER_RESPONSE** status and i allowed only to call accept claim and provide evidence.
After accept claim i am able only to call provide supporting info method, settle method is still not allowed.

So my question is how to trigger **CUSTOMER.DISPUTE.RESOLVED** event in sandbox and on what dispute state i need to call settle method from here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/v1#disputes-actions_adjudicate?

Request/Response examples

Dispute details right after open

```
{
    "dispute_id": "PP-D-40523",
    "create_time": "2021-03-03T08:47:08.000Z",
    "update_time": "2021-03-03T08:48:12.000Z",
    "disputed_transactions": [
        {
            "buyer_transaction_id": "35703532VD052404F",
            "seller_transaction_id": "92198049S8582070N",
            "create_time": "2021-03-03T08:41:55.000Z",
            "transaction_status": "COMPLETED",
            "gross_amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "29.99"
            },
            "buyer": {
                "name": "John Doe"
            },
            "seller": {
                "email": "sb-47flty3787626@business.example.com",
                "merchant_id": "TQNC9P6W9822C",
                "name": "John Doe's Test Store"
            },
            "items": [], 
            "seller_protection_eligible": true
        }
    ],  
    "reason": "UNAUTHORISED",
    "status": "WAITING_FOR_SELLER_RESPONSE",
    "dispute_amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "29.99"
    },  
    "dispute_life_cycle_stage": "CHARGEBACK",
    "dispute_channel": "INTERNAL",
    "extensions": {
        "buyer_contacted_time": "2021-02-11T17:50:48.000Z"
    },  
    "seller_response_due_date": "2021-03-24T08:47:50.000Z",
    "allowed_response_options": {
        "accept_claim": {
            "accept_claim_types": [
                "REFUND"
            ]
        }
    },  
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-40523",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-40523/provide-evidence",
            "rel": "provide_evidence",
            "method": "POST"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-40523/accept-claim",
            "rel": "accept_claim",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]   
}
```

After provide evidence

```
{
    "dispute_id": "PP-D-40523",
    "create_time": "2021-03-03T08:47:08.000Z",
    "update_time": "2021-03-03T11:01:55.000Z",
    "disputed_transactions": [
        {
            "buyer_transaction_id": "35703532VD052404F",
            "seller_transaction_id": "92198049S8582070N",
            "create_time": "2021-03-03T08:41:55.000Z",
            "transaction_status": "COMPLETED",
            "gross_amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "29.99"
            },
            "buyer": {
                "name": "John Doe"
            },
            "seller": {
                "email": "sb-47flty3787626@business.example.com",
                "merchant_id": "TQNC9P6W9822C",
                "name": "John Doe's Test Store"
            },
            "items": [],
            "seller_protection_eligible": true
        }
    ],
    "reason": "UNAUTHORISED", 
    "status": "UNDER_REVIEW",
    "dispute_amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "29.99"
    },  
    "dispute_life_cycle_stage": "CHARGEBACK",
    "dispute_channel": "INTERNAL",
    "extensions": {
        "buyer_contacted_time": "2021-02-11T17:50:48.000Z"
    },  
    "evidences": [
        {
            "evidence_type": "OTHER",
            "documents": [
                {
                    "name": "ava.jpeg"
                }
            ],
            "notes": "Test",
            "source": "SUBMITTED_BY_SELLER",
            "date": "2021-03-03T11:01:56.000Z",
            "action_info": {
                "action": "PROVIDE_EVIDENCE"
            }
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-40523",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-40523/provide-supporting-info",
            "rel": "provide_supporting_info",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]
}
```

Another dispute after claim

```
{

    "dispute_id": "PP-D-40407",
    "create_time": "2021-03-02T08:17:07.000Z",
    "update_time": "2021-03-02T08:47:05.000Z",
    "disputed_transactions": [
        {
            "buyer_transaction_id": "1VS7234539684123P",
            "seller_transaction_id": "2S50928513331053U",
            "create_time": "2021-03-02T08:09:49.000Z",
            "transaction_status": "COMPLETED",
            "gross_amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "29.99"
            },
            "buyer": {
                "name": "John Doe"
            },
            "seller": {
                "email": "sb-47flty3787626@business.example.com",
                "merchant_id": "TQNC9P6W9822C",
                "name": "John Doe's Test Store"
            },
            "items": [],
            "seller_protection_eligible": true
        }
    ],
    "reason": "UNAUTHORISED",
    "status": "UNDER_REVIEW",
    "dispute_amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "29.99"
    },
    "dispute_life_cycle_stage": "CHARGEBACK",
    "dispute_channel": "INTERNAL",
    "extensions": {
        "buyer_contacted_time": "2021-02-11T17:50:48.000Z"
    },
    "evidences": [
        {
            "evidence_type": "OTHER",
            "documents": [],
            "notes": "Refund.",
            "source": "SUBMITTED_BY_SELLER",
            "date": "2021-03-02T08:47:06.000Z",
            "action_info": {
                "action": "ACCEPT_CLAIM",
                "response_option": "REFUND"
            }
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-40407",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-40407/provide-supporting-info",
            "rel": "provide_supporting_info",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]
}
```

Adjudicate on dispute with evidence

Request

```
POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/PP-D-40523/adjudicate
{
    "adjudication_outcome": "BUYER_FAVOR"
}
```

Response

```
{
    "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "message": "Invalid request - see details",
    "debug_id": "6aadbbc916b3c",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/v1/#errors",
    "details": [
        {
            "issue": "ACTION_NOT_ALLOWED_IN_CURRENT_DISPUTE_STATE"
        }
    ],
    "links": []
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your examples, PayPal don't even have examples in their documentation.  and in 2019 they did not have "adjudications" sections. they are kind of developing it as we speak, and they don't update the documentation. So unprofessional of them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get it to an 'UNDER_REVIEW' by PayPal state *before* you can trigger the adjudication one way or the other.

So if it is 'WAITING_FOR_SELLER_RESPONSE' you should provide evidence; there is a call for that.

You may also need to make an offer and deny the offer, or escalate to claim.

This tool may be useful for understanding the potential steps: https://www.paypal.com/apex/product-profile/customerDisputes/

Comment: After providing evidence dispute status changed to UNDER_REVIEW. Calling adjudicate resulted in ACTION_NOT_ALLOWED_IN_CURRENT_DISPUTE_STATE. Make offer to resolve leads to the same action not allowed, escalate to claim is not possible because dispute was created already in the claim stage.

Comment: Well if you want help here you'll have to provide more details, including full request+response logs in your question of the calls that fail

Comment: updated question with the request/response examples